# My laravel project start page is not opening

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, git-bash

I have install **Laravel** in my pc using **composer**.

I used **gitbash** and started xampp control server

1. First I've changed my directory.
2. Then I've ran a command `composer create-project laravel/laravel  project_1`. After the command had run, it installed laravel and all necessary file and key was successfully set.
3. Then I again changed my directory to `project_1`
4. Then I ran another command `php artisan serve`. After running this command **Laravel development server started** and **127.0.0.1:8000** this ip has genrated.
5. I copied the id and paste it in my browser url bar.(I copied and pasted it without using keyboard. I only used mouse)

but when I provided the ip the **project_1** starting page did not open.
The page was loading and it is still loading.

[image]

what can I do? Please help

**logs folder**

[image]

Comment: Hello @Alien, check the php version and other basic requirements in your system. which php version are you using?

Comment: `php 7.2.12` is installed

Comment: okay, please check project_1\storage\logs\laravel you might find issue there.

Comment: please check laravel log so we can understand whats the problem

Comment: in logs folder there is no file name laravel excepte a file with no name. ther have 3 line of code I am adding the image of the code in my question plese chek this

Comment: It looks like your storage directory doesn't have full permission, make sure storage directory has read write permission.

Comment: problem recoverd by disabling anti virus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thing you did seems right to me in terms of Laravel requirements, so lets check some other possible issues:

1. make sure that your internet connection isn't configured to use
   proxy, if so make sure you excluded your local address.
2. if you are using Internet security suite software, make sure it doesn't block your requests, this vary from software to another but you might test this by deactivating the software for a while until you try.

now that's what I have in mind, I hope it help.

Comment: how to check these 2 issues?

Comment: as for 1, go within chrome to setting>Advanced>Open Proxy Settings

Comment: for the second issue, it vary, do you actually use any antivirus/internet security suite? if so, just turn it off for a while and then try to access the local address

Comment: deactivate it (or turn it off) for a while and try to access, make sure to deactivate any chrome plugin belongs to it as well

Comment: after disabling the anti virous it worked. Thanks a lot brother

Answer (score 5):

Here is my contribution, I cannot say what is the cause but I have a solution for it; because I have such as a challenge.

run

> php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public

Note that the 8000 is your port, and this could be any 4-digit number.

*I hope this helps*

Answer (score 1):

First, stop the `php artisan serve`

After changing directory go to inside your project folder, you can run `php artisan serve`. Then a localhost URL will be generated for you where you can see your project in the browser

If you have PHP installed locally and you would like to use PHP's built-in development server will start a development server at http://localhost:8000

Comment: sorry I can't get you. May you make it little more clear?

Comment: Hello Udhav, as Alien mention, he already moved to project_1 and then he execute php artisan serve so I don't think it helps.

Comment: @Alien You've already tried it so it will not work, can you please share your server requirement, your Laravel version, and your PHP version

Comment: 5.7.25 is my Laravel version

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install Laragon and forget about Xampp for now. This is really cool tool and you'll start much quicker. I did try to resolve few issues with Xampp myself and always wasted a lot of time. You can google tutorials later for it as well. Plenty of info out there.

As well it comes with in house installer for Laravel ;) and more :).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not coping the url from Git Bash through command, it will stop running the project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not using antivirus specially avast antivirus.